# Lost all apps on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I encountered a bug, none of the task buttons were responding, luckily I found [this fix](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/fix-windows-10-taskbar-not-working-fix-build-10074/6b13e8b6-b30b-4e80-aa7c-a4a3939195ea?auth=1).

But now I suddenly don't have the app store icon and all the apps have disappeared (I also noticed I have a bit more hard drive space)

Is there a fix to this problem? Maybe I have to install windows store? Or is the only solution to refresh windows? (the option is actually called "Reset this PC")

Comment: I understood that this would allow me to keep all of my programs, but will I still be able to roll back to windows 8.1 (which is in windows.old folder) ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? : Press Windows key + R to open run box. Type WSReset.exe and hit enter.

Comment: That was a much better idea than resetting. But I still can't get the store icon back on the task bar. Help?

Comment: @zoran404 - So why did you accept the answer as the solution if it isn't the solution?

Comment: @Ramhound because it started the store and I'm able to reinstall the apps.

Comment: @zoran404 If you can open the store, can you right click and pin it to the taskbar?

Comment: It might be worth saying what this task runs, in case someone else does it, and loses something they don't want to.

Comment: WSReset.exe opens the store and, as I read, clears the cash. I have pin that to the taskbar, but I don't think that's the intended use for it (considering a console window is also open). If I don't find a way to get the original shortcut to work I might reset windows to make sure everything works fine.

Comment: I just found that I can still open my apps from the store app and that wsreset starts this app: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.8.12.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.Mobile.exe